# Sharepoint 2010 - Specify default settings and columns for new document libraries

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How do you specify a template for new document libraries, in which new libraries are created with some preset settings like reviosioning enabled and some default columns are included in the default view like Version and CheckIn.

I am looking at doing this at site collection level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic options:

1. Through the browser, you can customize a Document Library the way you want it and then save it as a custom list template by selecting Settings > Document Library Settings > Save document library as template.
2. In Visual Studio, you can create a feature that includes a custom list definition. For more information, see [How to: Create a Custom List Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466023.aspx). To enable versions, set the VersioningEnabled and possibly the EnableMinorVersions attributes on the [List element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415091.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own ListDefinition via Visual Studio.
List definition would include all possible content types for list, columns, views.
Also you can provision your own site columns if needed.
Then configure your feature for site collection level and use it =)

In order to makethis process easier try creating ListDefinition for Content Type and select a content type. (in your case i suppose it would be Document)